# How to Enable Tracing at the Page Level (Razor Syntax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to enable tracing at the page level using the razor syntax?

ASPX Syntax:

```
<@Page trace="true" ... />
```

**Update:**
I'm interested in this primarily because I'm studying for the MCTS exam.   I know the exam doesn't include Razor, but I'm learning both syntax's at the same time.

Comment: If you Breakpoint the line in the controller before the page is called, you can usually also step through the page too.

Comment: I'm not trying to step into the page.  I'm trying to enable tracing on the page.

Answer (score 0):

By inference, from what I can see, the answer is "you can't control page level trace with Razor", this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790451/trace-warn-doesnt-output-trace-messages-in-mvc) has some links to Glimpse which helps you debug.

I'm neutral to whether this is good or bad, but it would be nice to be able to see some reasoning for this.